# JQuery: Trigger click event

Tags: jquery

How can i trigger a click on a radio button if I click on the element `click`? The element `click` always comes after the radio button and this should work with multiple radio buttons. Any Idea how this could be done?

```
<div class="option">
<input type="radio" class="option--input" id="radio1" name="radio">
<div class="click"></div>
</div>

<div class="option">
<input type="radio" class="option--input" id="radio2" name="radio">
<div class="click"></div>
</div>
```

**Here is my try:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.click', function(event) {
    $(this).closest(".option--input").prev().click();
});
```

Comment: use this context with `.prev()` or `.parent().find()` (if multiple radio button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for jQuery at all as there is already a HTML element exactly for this purpose: [`<label />`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element)

```css
.click {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="option">
  <input type="radio" class="option--input" id="radio1" name="radio1">
  <label for="radio1">
    <div class="click"></div>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="option">
  <input type="radio" class="option--input" id="radio2" name="radio1">
  <label for="radio2">
    <div class="click"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```